# How to handle special characters in command line arguments for a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, sh, command-line-arguments

I have the following shell script where I just want to print out the first argument as it is passed in

**Code:**

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == "" ]; then
    exit 1
fi

echo $1
```

Lets say name of the script is `testarg.sh` which is called as follows - `testarg.sh abc`. Great!

Above shell script works if I pass simple arguments like "abc" or "xyz123". And calling it like `testarg.sh xyz123` prints out "xyz123". All good!

**Problem:**
*But* if does print the content accurately if I pass a complex string with special characters. Lets say I called it like this below:

```
./testarg.sh $6$nB3/jwAqgRcS9LN7$8c5InVbk5SLFiwuz9Xm6EHHRuZHMI0ggMhmxJ7Pr7NuBZ0TXtProuZ6LpQ6ZrFySly12cbGmWHsFpukEKAzdW.
```

**Question:**
In the above call I want to pass `$6$nB3/jwAqgRcS9LN7$8c5InVbk5SLFiwuz9Xm6EHHRuZHMI0ggMhmxJ7Pr7NuBZ0TXtProuZ6LpQ6ZrFySly12cbGmWHsFpukEKAzdW.` as the argument and print it out exactly as it is including the slash and dots. Do I need to apply special tricks?

I don't want the user of my script to bother inserting special escape characters for the slashes. Is there a way I can handle this nicely in my script and get the value of `$1` as it is to print it out accurately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call the script with single quotes around the argument. There is no way to make this work by changing the code of the script.

```
./testarg.sh '$6$nB3/jwAqgRcS9LN7$8c5InVbk5SLFiwuz9Xm6EHHRuZHMI0ggMhmxJ7Pr7NuBZ0TXtProuZ6LpQ6ZrFySly12cbGmWHsFpukEKAzdW.'
```